# Populate dictionary values in a dropdown with django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am returning a dictionary to a variable under views.py as follows:

```
dict1={1:["a","b"],2:["c","d"]}
def home(requests):
    return render(requests,'home/index.html',{"dict":dict1})
```

I have the following HTML Form with a drop down and a multi-select text area:
index.html

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">

            <option>o1</option>
            <option>o2</option>

          </select>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect2">
            <option>title1</option>
            <option>title2</option>
            <option>title3</option>
            <option>title4</option>
            <option>title5</option>
          </select>
```

I need to populate keys in the first dropdown and whenever I select a key from the dropdown, the other dropdown must be populated with values corresponding to the key.I tried with

```
{%for}
```

but I am unable to access the key-value pairs.

Comment: Should be able to iterate through them via ```{% for key, values in dict.items %}```

Comment: I tried it already but in my case it is more of event firing.Like when I select key dropdown values dropdown must be populated @LewisHepburn

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/select/paired.php. You will have to incorporate javascript though.

Comment: @LewisHepburn I looked into it but I need to use my Django dict variable in javascript and I need to trigger an event when some value is selected

Comment: I could use it but when I am trying to print the values it just displays numbers instead of values @LewisHepburn

Comment: Could you update your question to see your issue?